# Having a hard time with using classes and objects in python in which there is no error

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, output

Main.py

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

app.py

```
from main import Student

student1 = Student("Mikah", "Computer science", 4.2, False)
student2 = Student("Mike", "Computer science", 4.3, True)

print(student2.is_on_probation)
```

This is my code that I am trying to output while watching the python tutorial by free code camp, and for some reason it gives no errors but doesn't output anything at all. Is this a version diff or something else since this video came out a couple years ago.

Comment: The formatting on this post for the code I know is not right and will not work, so know that I indented in my code and did not do it like this. and Also used python 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on learning new skills.  I see two changes.

1. You want to make sure you are attempting to run `app.py`.  If you run `main.py` nothing would happen. Usually you want your run code in `main.py`.
2. Looks like you missed some underscores for your `__init__()` Function, this [site has more info.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_class_init.asp)

Your code should read

**main.py**
Note the underscores before and after `init`

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

**app.py**
No changes here

```
from main import Student

student1 = Student("Mikah", "Computer science", 4.2, False)
student2 = Student("Mike", "Computer science", 4.3, True)

print(student2.is_on_probation)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using pycharm and when I clicked the play button and I think it might have tried to start main instead of app and when I right clicked app.py and ran it and it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. If you run "app.py", you will get the output "True".

Make sure you are running "app.py" and not "main.py". If you run main, you will get nothing printed because in that file you dont asked python to run anything, you just created a class (Lets say that "main.py" has information but no instructions and thats why it wont make anything if you run it).

Comment: Thank you, I was using pycharm and when I clicked the play button and I think it might have tried to start main instead of app and when I right clicked app.py and ran it and it ended up working.